# Angular 7 and D3.js V4 - how to stop rectangle collisions in real time chart?

Tags: angular, d3.js, webapi2

I am using D3.js V4 library for real-time chart presentation. New dot point is drawing every 2s, and with dot we have the information about weight.

Everything looks fine, but I don't know how to handle rectangle collisions (mark as red). 
What is the best way to handle this kind of situation?
Is it possible to configure the chart to show the weight information only for last 5 dots, or n numbers?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you drawing the labels yourself? If so, have a look at https://github.com/d3/d3-force

Comment: Yes. It's just simple rectangle object with the text.

Comment: Example will be appreciated. If some one had a similar situation.